# Hi, I am looking for retaining a state of sorting/pagination while navigating on pages

Tags: reactjs

I am using react data grids. Functionality I want to achieve is:
I selected page# and sorted in desc order.
I click on data grid row and go to details page.
I click on back button details page, the page# and sorting order I selected should be retained.
please provide inputs how can we achieve using react grid?

Comment: Please add the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user-selected values in the localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('sort', 'desc');
```

and then when the user returns back to the current page fetch the values from localStorage on the component mount lifecycle method

```
let sort = localStorage.getItem('sort');
```

and pass it to the grid Component.